# How to get the new value to the top position of the listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

How to get the new value to the top poistion of the listview  when I entered the digit in a edittext.
Am getting the new value, which is given in the edittext,adding to the last position of the listview.
But I want the new value must be added to the top position of the listview.
Please can anyone help me in doing so?

Comment: Which data storage are you using to populate ListView? ArrayList or Array? or any other?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();` then you can add the data to ArrayList at the 0 index and call `notifyDataSetChanged();` to re-populate your ListView.

```
arrayList.add(0, "First");
```

Answer (score 1):

just Reverse Your For Loop from size of ArrayList to 0.
Like This following Code ...

```
int j = ArrayList.size();

for (int i =j-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: OP wants to show the data in the ListView so you can do it like this in the Adapter Class.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a button to the View containing the EditText and then when the user clicks that button get the value of the EditText and add it to the ListAdapter.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    //Get the data from the edittext
    String s = editText.getText().toString();
    //Add it to your adapter
    adapter.add(s);
    //Refresh the adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
});
```

Here are some links you might want to check out:
[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)
[EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)